# Calculating odds of Football game results using C#

Tags: c#, probability

I have a question which probably breaks down into 2 questions; What is the name of the mathematical theory I'm trying to find, and how is it most efficiently done in C#.

Essentially, I have the problem that I'm calculating the cumulative odds of guessing the outcomes of 5+ games correctly.

The way I have built my program thus far is that the matchups and their respective odds are entered into the system, at which point the code assembles them into a list containing all match-ups, the winner and the odds of that happening; this is done iteratively:

```
foreach (var game in games)
{
    gamesList.Add(new GameBet
    {
        Home = game.Home,
        Away = game.Away,
        BetResult = game.GameResult,
        Odds = game.Odds
    });
}
```

where by the info is added into the games list using:

```
gamesAndOdds.Add(Result.Create(Teams.Russia, Teams.Slovakia, GameResult.Home, (decimal)2.37));
gamesAndOdds.Add(Result.Create(Teams.Russia, Teams.Slovakia, GameResult.Away, (decimal)3.50));
gamesAndOdds.Add(Result.Create(Teams.Russia, Teams.Slovakia, GameResult.Tie, (decimal)3.2));
```

Essentially I now have a big list containing all the games I'm looking to take into my calculation, with the odds for the 3 different possibilities.

Now, my question comes down to how I can see which games/results would provide the highest cumulative odds; viz. which odds calculated together give me the highest multiplier for my winnings.

Currently I have implemented a terribly nested ForEach loop construct:

```
for (var spain = 0; spain < 3; spain++)
{
    for (var ireland = 0; ireland < 3; ireland++)
    {
        for (var belg = 0; belg < 3; belg++)
        {
            for (var aust = 0; aust < 3; aust++)
            {
                for (var port = 0; port < 3; port++)
                {
                    counter++;
                    var spainOdd = gamesList.First(x => (int)x.BetResult == spain && x.Home == Teams.Russia);
                    var ireOdd = gamesList.First(x => (int)x.BetResult == ireland && x.Home == Teams.Ukraine);
                    var belgOdd = gamesList.First(x => (int)x.BetResult == belg && x.Home == Teams.France);
                    var austOdd = gamesList.First(x => (int)x.BetResult == aust && x.Home == Teams.England);
                    var portOdd = gamesList.First(x => (int)x.BetResult == port && x.Home == Teams.Germany);
                    var totalOdd = spainOdd.Odds * ireOdd.Odds * belgOdd.Odds * austOdd.Odds * portOdd.Odds;
                    multipliers.Add(totalOdd);
                    var bets = new List<GameBet>() { spainOdd, ireOdd, belgOdd, austOdd, portOdd };
                    BetList.Add(new BetList() { Bets = bets, Odds = totalOdd });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does give me the results, and since this is small project the calculation times aren't so pressing; but as a thought experiment, how would I go about doing this in a more generic way?
(I'm well aware that betting is a terrible thing and likely not to be profitable, this is purely for the thought experiment)

Comment: This question better fits to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_modelling